# Button Component Cuts off my custom View

Tags: java, android, xml, android-custom-view

My button component takes space of my custom view class,if i put more it takes up more space,any reason why is that

My oncreate method :

```
  @Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_control);



    MyCustomPanel view = new MyCustomPanel(this);
    DisplayMetrics metrics;
    metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
    getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
    int height = getDPI(500, metrics);
    int width = getDPI(800,metrics);
    layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.r2) ;
    layout1 = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.l2);

    ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(width,
            height);
    layout.addView(view,params);
    }
```

This is my xml code :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="horizontal"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/r2"
android:gravity="bottom|start"
android:layout_gravity="bottom|start"
tools:context="company.ciso.com.wheelchair.Control">

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:gravity="top|end"
    android:layout_gravity="top|end"
    android:id="@+id/l2"
    >
   <Button
       style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:id="@+id/b1"
       android:text="S1" />

</LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

these are the screen shots
[image]
[image]

Additionally is there anyway to set gravity of my custom view.??

Comment: Care to post a screenshot?

Comment: posted,plz take a look

Comment: It is behaving as it should. What result are you expecting?

Comment: the left sections gets cut offed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update your layout with this code.

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/l2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_gravity="top|end"
        android:gravity="top|end"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/b1"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="S1" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/r2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:orientation="horizontal"></LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: we can understand your problem what you are actually up-to ..we dont know whats `MyCustomPanel ` better to add screen shot of your problem.

Comment: mycustompanel just draws some stuff nothing else,but i have added some screenshots take a look

Comment: @PuneetSharma  replace your layout with above one and let me know if still have issue?

Comment: THank you very very much it worked,i just made it layout_bottom instead of vertical and horizontal what was  the issue btw..???

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/114806/discussion-between-sohail-zahid-and-puneet-sharma).